# Boto+GoogleAppEnginer: "Unable to fetch URL: http://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/2010-11-01/distribution/<CF_DIST_ID>". Connection refused

Tags: python-2.7, boto, amazon-cloudfront, google-app-engine-python

I am running these code inside a google app engine project.

```
from boto import cloudfront

con = cloudfront.CloudFrontConnection(
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    AWS_SECRET_KEY
)

distro_info = con.get_distribution_info(DOWNLOAD_DIST_ID)
```

When it executes to the last line above I got a bunch of warning/error messages like this:

```
WARNING  2015-04-22 07:15:58,620 urlfetch_stub.py:504] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Content-Length', 'Host']
WARNING  2015-04-22 07:15:59,811 urlfetch_stub.py:504] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Content-Length', 'Host']
WARNING  2015-04-22 07:16:02,105 urlfetch_stub.py:504] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Content-Length', 'Host']
WARNING  2015-04-22 07:16:05,961 urlfetch_stub.py:504] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Content-Length', 'Host']
WARNING  2015-04-22 07:16:07,010 urlfetch_stub.py:504] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Content-Length', 'Host']
WARNING  2015-04-22 07:16:08,088 urlfetch_stub.py:504] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Content-Length', 'Host']
WARNING  2015-04-22 07:16:29,897 urlfetch_stub.py:504] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Content-Length', 'Host']
ERROR    2015-04-22 07:17:24,921 webapp2.py:1528] An error occured while connecting to the server: Unable to fetch URL: http://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/2010-11-01/distribution/XXXXX4K3XXXXX Error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/antkong/dev/test-signed-cookie/testmain.py", line 218, in get
    domain, cookies = generate_signed_cookies(s3resource, expire_minutes=expireLen)
  File "/Users/antkong/dev/test-signed-cookie/testmain.py", line 107, in generate_signed_cookies
    distro_info = con.get_distribution_info(DOWNLOAD_DIST_ID)
  File "lib/boto/cloudfront/__init__.py", line 158, in get_distribution_info
    return self._get_info(distribution_id, 'distribution', Distribution)
  File "lib/boto/cloudfront/__init__.py", line 86, in _get_info
    response = self.make_request('GET', uri)
  File "lib/boto/connection.py", line 1068, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler)
  File "lib/boto/connection.py", line 943, in _mexe
    response = connection.getresponse()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/dist27/gae_override/httplib.py", line 536, in getresponse
    'An error occured while connecting to the server: %s' % e)
error: An error occured while connecting to the server: Unable to fetch URL: http://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/2010-11-01/distribution/XXXXX4K3XXXXX Error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

If I run it as a standalone script there is no issue at all.

Anyone knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are using http URL, and CloudFront API is not available on http, only on https